# Updating and Deleting documents using NodeJS on Cloudant DB

Tags: node.js, cloudant

I was able to successfully query(select) and insert data into Cloudant database using HTTP /REST API. But I am not able to figure out - how to delete and modify documents.

**For Delete:** I tried the following code in nodejs
path : '/quick_loan_nosql_db_1?951b05d1b6aa100f4b94e5185674ef40/_rev=1-88963c755157188091f0d30115de18ce' 
part of the REST API Request with METHOD: DELETE.
But when I execute it deletes the entire database instead of the ID being specified.

**For Update**: Can some one provide a sample, I tried with PUT, but in response I got a Conflict data error.
Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: To delete a document take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32103420/deleting-a-document-from-cloudant-database-in-nodejs/37006669#37006669

Answer (score 1):

Nice! To answer your original question, you just have the "/" and the "?" in the wrong places. To recap:

`/quick_loan_nosql_db_1?951b05d1b6aa100f4b94e5185674ef40/_rev=1-88963c755157188091f0d30115de18ce`

should *instead* be:

`/quick_loan_nosql_db_1/951b05d1b6aa100f4b94e5185674ef40?_rev=1-88963c755157188091f0d30115de18ce`

Comment: Cool That should work. Think of it as you just need to provide the right path to the JSON doc with that ID in the `quick_loan_nosql_db_1` database, then you need to query for that particular doc's revision number. To the future!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way I figured out to perform the Update and Delete.

I used nano api:

Include nano by
 var nano =require('nano')('https://'+dbCredentials.user+':'+dbCredentials.password+'hostname:port/');
Please make sure to put the right user id and password

**For Update**

Update - you need to use insert api only, but with the right _id and _eval and the changes. For example:

```
 nanodb.insert({ "_id": "3a1cc8c7f955f895131c3289f5144eab", "_rev": "2-    7040205a1c9270ad696724458399ac94",  "name": "Tom", "employername":"Google"},      function(err, body, header) {
if (err) {
    console.log('[db.insert] ', err);
    return;
  }
  console.log('you have inserted the rabbit.')
  console.log(body);
});
```

The above code will perform an update on the given id and the _rev. There will be a new revision number updated and the id will remain same. If you miss the ID or revision number, it will throw a conflict error.

**For Delete**
Simple use nano.destroy with the id and the revision number

```
nanodb.destroy("3a1cc8c7f955f895131c3289f5144eab","3-3e39e2298f109414cef1310449e0fd5c",function(err, body, header) {
    if (err) {
    console.log('[db.insert] ', err);
    return;
  }
  console.log('you have inserted the rabbit.')
  console.log(body);

    });
```

Using Nano like framework API is better than making REST API calls over http for accessing the cloudant Database.

Hope this helps for people who want to connect to Cloudant db from NodeJS